# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to iterate through a string

Tags: java, string, logic

I'm trying to write an application that takes user input and converts it to morse code

Function code:

```
    public static String[] stringToMorseSequence(String stringOfLetters){
        int lenStringOfLetters = stringOfLetters.length();
        String output[] = new String[1];

        String compInterpreted = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < lenStringOfLetters; i++) {
            String focus = String.valueOf(stringOfLetters.charAt(i));
            String nextCharacter = "";
            if (i != lenStringOfLetters) {
                nextCharacter = String.valueOf(stringOfLetters.charAt(i + 1));
            } else {
                nextCharacter = "END";
            }

            if (focus == " ") {
                compInterpreted = compInterpreted + "#";
            } else {
                String morseSequence = processCharacter(focus);
                if (morseSequence == "") {

                } else if (i == lenStringOfLetters) {
                    compInterpreted = compInterpreted + "!";
                } else if (nextCharacter != "END") {
                    if (nextCharacter != " "){
                        compInterpreted = compInterpreted + morseSequence + "@";
                    } else {
                        compInterpreted = compInterpreted + morseSequence;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.i("MORSE","Computer interpretable morse sequence = " + compInterpreted);
        output[0] = compInterpreted;

        String prettySequence = "";
        for(int i = 0; i-1 < output[0].length(); i++) {
            switch(String.valueOf(output[0].charAt(i))){
                case("#"):
                    prettySequence = prettySequence + "  ";
                case("@"):
                    prettySequence = prettySequence + " ";
                default:
                    prettySequence = prettySequence + output[0].charAt(i);
            }
        }
        Log.i("MORSE","Human interpretable morse sequence = " + prettySequence);
        output[1] = prettySequence;

        return output;
    }
```

And I appear to be receiving this exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: me.merhlim.jessica.morsecode, PID: 5687
              java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
                  at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
                  at me.merhlim.jessica.morsecode.MorseProcessing.stringToMorseSequence(MorseProcessing.java:16)
                  at me.merhlim.jessica.morsecode.texttomorse$7.onClick(texttomorse.java:112)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                  at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:108)
```

I know its a logical error, but I'm unsure where this error is, or how to solve it. As mentioned by the error message, its an index error when trying to parse a specific character in a string, but I am unsure what logic I've got incorrect for this error to be set off

I'm new to java, and its late at night, so maybe I'm just not fully understanding the problem in the logic I'm writing

If this isn't enough information to answer my problem I can provide more

Thank you for taking the time to read this and if you provide assistance, it is much appreciated 
-Jessica

Comment: Hint: `i != lenStringOfLetters` will always be true.

Comment: Also, 

    else if (i == lenStringOfLetters)

will never be true.

Comment: The clue is in the exception text. The length of the string is `length=10` and the index you are asking for is `index=10`. Since indexes are 0 based, an index the same as or greater than the length will cause this exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when i is at 9 which is less than length 10, calling

```
nextCharacter = String.valueOf(stringOfLetters.charAt(i + 1));
```

will try to get the character at the 10th position. However, the length of the string is only 10 and last character is at position 9, which leads to an string index out of bound exception. you might want to change this

```
if (i != lenStringOfLetters) {
```

to

```
if (i != lenStringOfLetters-1) {
```

Comment: I changed it and i now appear to be reciving this problem

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: me.merhlim.jessica.morsecode, PID: 7864
                  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Comment: Is this a different problem? or part of the same one?

Comment: @Merhlim which line is the exception throwing at ?

Comment: @Merhlim is the exception throwing at this line now instead ? `for(int i = 0; i-1 < output[0].length(); i++) {`

Comment: at me.merhlim.jessica.morsecode.MorseProcessing.stringToMorseSequence(MorseProcessing.java:53)

Does this contain the line number?

Comment: @Merhlim yes, it means that it is thrown by line 53 of MorseProcessing.java

Comment: @Merhlim found the issue. `output[1] = prettySequence;` your output is only an array with size 1. output[1] will throw an error. only output[0] exists. it's either you change it to `output[0] = prettySequence;` or initliaze output as an array with size 2 `String output[] = new String[2];`

Comment: It took it!

But unfortunately I diddnt get an output

I/MORSE: Computer interpretable morse sequence = 
I/MORSE: Human interpretable morse sequence =

Comment: @Merhlim i tried running the code and am able to get I/MORSE as human interpretable morse sequence i do however changed `for(int i = 0; i-1 < output[0].length(); i++) {` to `for(int i = 0; i < output[0].length() ; i++) {`

Comment: I think its a problem with concatenating strings now, it's attempting to concatenate strings to compInterpreted as it goes along, and it doesnt seem to be doing that

Comment: @Merhlim can you open a new question with the updated code it seems like a different problem already

Comment: Im running a few tests before i jump to that, thank you for all of the help